# No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to read a CSV in Flutter, but I am getting an error when running.

import 'package:csv_reader/csv_reader.dart';

```
class CityCreator{
  CityCreator() {
    var myCSV = CSV.from(url : 'resources/travel.csv', delimiter: ",", title:true);
  }
}
```

I have imported the file and I have it in a folder called resources.

I get this error:

```
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI resources/travel.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `csv_reader` library](https://pub.dev/documentation/csv_reader/latest/csv_reader/CSV/CSV.from.html) is treating that input as a URL, and passing it to `HttpClient`:

```
await HttpClient()
    .getUrl(Uri.parse(this.url))
...
```

that means it's failing [when trying to connect](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/ecd82166c31297db61f062c9ba509a2d498d6cef/sdk/lib/_http/http_impl.dart#L2308):

```
  if (uri.host.isEmpty) {
    throw new ArgumentError("No host specified in URI $uri");
```

Consider a [different CSV library](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) which will read from local files:

```
final input = new File('a/csv/file.txt').openRead();
final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(new CsvToListConverter()).toList();
```

or one of the suggestions in the [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv+dart).

Comment: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'travel.csv' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2).         I get this error now, it doesn't work even if I put it in a assets folder